# Creating a Hovercard with jQuery Hovercard and custom data attributes

Tags: jquery-plugins, hover, jquery-hover

I need some help about creating more HoverCards with [this plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard) ([download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/jquery.hovercard.min.js)). I just created a code demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/love4all1080/rLwkJ/). Do you have any recommendations about this?

JavaScript:

```
$('.babe-hover').hovercard({ 
    detailsHTML: $(this).attr('data-control').html(),
    width:278 
});
```

HTML:

```
 <ul class="demo">
<li>
    <a href="#"><span class="babe-hover" data-control="control-01">William Johnson</span></a>
    <div id="control-01" style="display: none;">
        <p class="s-desc">Address: 64 Newman Street.</p>
        <ul class="s-stats">
            <li>Tweets<br><span class="s-count">1337</span></li>     
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#"><span class="babe-hover" data-control="control-02">Hanson Thomas</span></a>
    <div id="control-02" style="display: none;">
        <p class="s-desc">Address: 64 Newman Street.</p>
        <ul class="s-stats">
            <li>Tweets<br><span class="s-count">1337</span></li>     
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

​

Answer (score 2):

Now it working with some help from [the author](http://designwithpc.com/)

```
$('.babe-hover').each(function(){    
var $this = $(this),
    myControlId = $this.attr('data-control'),
    htmlForHovercard = $('#'+ myControlId).html();

$this.hovercard({ 
    detailsHTML: htmlForHovercard,
    width:278 
}); 
});
```

anyway thank @egasimus for ur suggest :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're asking: why doesn't this work?

You're trying to call the `.html()` method on what `$(this).attr('data-control')` returns. `$(this).attr('data-control')`, however, only returns a string, and you need to obtain the corresponding element in order to use `.html()`. The following code works for me:

```
$("#" + $(this).attr('data-control')).html()
```

I.e., "select the element whose id equals this element's data-control attribute, and call .html() on it."